# Is it possible to have GitHub Readme images follow redirects?

Tags: testing, github, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, pytest

I'm trying to add a test coverage badge to the Readme of a private repository on GitHub. Our continuous integration process saves out the image to a secured Google Cloud Storage bucket that's not accessible to the public, and should remain that way.

Google's authorization layer is smart enough that if I go to the URL for the image, I'm automatically redirected to the resource with a valid auto-generated signed URL.

E.g., if I go to `http://storage.cloud.google.com/secret-files/mysecretfile.png`, then if I'm logged in and allowed to view it, I'm automatically redirected to something like `https://blahblah-apidata.googleusercontent.com/download/storage/v1/b/secret-files/o/mysecretfile.png?key=verylongkey`, where I can load the image.

This seemed perfect. Reference the canonical path in the GitHub Readme, authenticated users see the image, unauthenticated users are still blocked, we don't have to make the file public, and we don't have to do anything complicated.

Except that GitHub is proxying the image request, meaning that it will always be unauthenticated. My browser is loading something like `https://camo.githubusercontent.com/mysecretimage.png`.

Is there a clever way to work around this? Or do I need to go back to the drawing board?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All images on github.com are proxied using the Camo image proxy.  There are a couple reasons for this:

- It preserves the privacy of users.  It isn't possible for a document to track users by directing them to a different site or using cookies to track them.
- It means images can be cached and served at an appropriate size.
- GitHub can have a very strict content security policy that does not allow loading from untrusted sites, which means that any sort of accidental security problem (like an XSS) is a lot less likely to work.

Note the last part.  Even if you found some sneaky way to get another image URL to render properly in the website, your browser wouldn't load it because it violates the `Content-Security-Policy` header the site sent, and moreover, your browser would tattle about that to the reporting URL that GitHub provided.

So any image URL you provide will need to be readable by GitHub's image proxy and it won't be possible to serve different content to different users.

Comment: This is very helpful. Is there a way in GitHub to, say, bless just the GitHub image proxy? Or do most people who build these features just make the resources quasi-public?

Comment: I don't know if there's a way to explicitly allow just the GitHub image proxy for your image.  There's probably multiple IPs used.  I'd just make the image quasi-public.  After all, nobody cares whether your tests for a private repo are actually passing or failing, and nobody is harmed if someone learns that fact.